# oracle sql developer edit fields

Tags: sql, mysql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have recently tried oracle sql developer 2.11 and 3 EA 2 both 32-bit windows (although I have tried 2.11 64bit as well). One issue that has been driving me nuts is in data view I cant seem to edit the data in fields, from a MYSQL, database directly, however, I can manipulate data via SQL so it isn't a permissions problem.

Can anyone please tell me how to enable it so I can click on fields and edit, I am sure this is possible from looking at video on youtube, however, these demos are with oracle so I wonder if this is a restriction with mysql? Anyone?

PS Also have the same issue with MS Access Database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think its a restriction.

Oracle tables have a built-in identifier called ROWID that is unique to any record in a table. As such, the data browser can pull out the ROWID for each row it is displaying. When you change column 'pet' from 'CAT' to 'DOG' it simply generates an UPDATE table SET PET='DOG' WHERE ROWID = ....

There are a few issues with this (eg tables with fine grained access control/row level security) so it doesn't always work even for Oracle tables.

Technically the equivalent can be done by determining the primary key columns, but that would require the table has a primary key enforced, so excluding updatable views. And then there is the hassle of determing which columns are the primary key ones and using those values (data types etc). In short, it is a lot of extra work under the hood, all database specific, so I'm not surprised that functionality hasn't been developed.

Comment: Just FYI, SQL Developer also uses ORA_ROWSCN to try and guess if someone else just changed your data before you commit your changes.  Which is a cool way to check if multiple people are editing the same thing at the same time.  But unfortunately ORA_ROWSCN may change depending on access paths, so it's not uncommon to get concurrency errors when you're the only one changing data.  I submitted a bug for this years ago, I wonder if it ever got fixed.  </rant>

Comment: Many thanks I dont actually use Oracle i was looking for a tool for mainly MYSQL however I though I had come across a great universal tool.  I like to edit fields directly without using SQL when testing/writing routines before I move on to more rigorous testing via TDD and BDD.

Comment: I think I will use MYSQL Workbench